# Unloading XIB from memory

Tags: iphone

So here's my setup:

- User spins PickerWheel, chooses which section of the app to navigate to.
- The app loads a UIViewController from a XIB file and pushes it on to the navigationController stack
- User can pop back at anytime and choose another section to navigate to - the viewController is (supposed to be) completely destroyed and re-allocated for the new XIB file

It seems simple, but each of these sections is very resource intensive. I can't find a good way to completely clear the XIB out of memory when they pop back - I try just calling [viewController release], and while it works and ends up calling the -(void)dealloc method of the UIViewController subclass, some of the contents from the XIB file still stay in memory (I can see them there in ObjectAllocations, and I can see a lot of memory left over in ActivityMonitor).

Basically what I am asking is what is the best way to completely remove a dynamically-loaded XIB from memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
viewController.view = nil;
```

If `view` is nil on a NIB-controlled UIViewController, then it will automatically reload the NIB the next time it's requested. This is exactly how `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` works.

As I think about this more, this won't immediately drop your IBOutlets, which in your case probably matters. So you need to also implement the special memory management for IBOutlets described in [Memory Management of Nib Objects](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW4).

You need to implement `-setView:` as described. Read this entire document carefully. I've written up a quick summary of the key points in [Memory Managing IBOutlets](http://robnapier.net/blog/memory-managing-iboutlets-17).

Comment: Wow. Three words cancels out three hours of work :P You, sir, are a champion. Much appreciated.

Comment: This is perhaps one of the most important posts on StackOverFlow - iPhone. Rob Napier is my MVP. If you're doing anything that requires complex Navigation and UIViewControllers, please, please, please pay attention to this post! Thanks Rob!

Comment: What ????!! Why is this not written in red bold letters at the top of the SDK documentation ? This post helps me so much. Know I understand why my application is not releasing all its memory